# Google Picker and save selected file in folder in angular 8

Tags: angular

I am not able to save selected file in project folder or not able to get data for selected file in Angular 8.

I'm implementing Google Picker API in Angular 8.this is my code when i am writing any code  in set callback function than i am getting error. can

```
loadGoogleDrive() {
    gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': this.onAuthApiLoad.bind(this) });
   gapi.load('picker', { 'callback': this.onPickerApiLoad.bind(this) });
  }

  onAuthApiLoad() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': this.clientId,
        'scope': this.scope,
        'immediate': false
      },
      this.handleAuthResult);
  }

  onPickerApiLoad() {
    this.pickerApiLoaded = true;
  }

  handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    let src;
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      if (authResult.access_token) {
        let view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,video/mp4,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/pdf,text/csv");
        let pickerBuilder = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();

        let picker = pickerBuilder.addViewGroup(
          new google.picker.ViewGroup(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS).
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.PRESENTATIONS).addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)).
          enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN).
          setOAuthToken(authResult.access_token).
          addView(view).
          addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView()).
          setCallback(function (e) {
            if (e[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
              let doc = e[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
              src = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
              console.log("Document selected is", doc, "and URL is ", src)
            }
          }).
          build();
        picker.setVisible(true);

      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you include the error?

Comment: Please suggest how i can save selected file in folder in angular 8 and save selected file data in database as well